# Rewrite rule IIS 8, removing .html extension

Tags: wordpress, windows, iis, url-rewriting, server

I need to add a .html file to a Wordpress installation that works on IIS.
What I have now is:

//mydomain.com/userpage.html

What I want to achieve is:
//mydomain.com/userpage/

I fixed all the other rules (pretty urls and so on...) but which code should I use to achieve the above result?

Thank you!

Max

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="hide userpage.html">
    <match url="^userpage/?$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/userpage.html" />
</rule>
```